# Passing "thread number" to pthread_create

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm creating a set number of threads and dispatching them to execute a function I created (`createAndInsertCandy`). I want to pass in an integer to the thread-create function to track which thread is executing my function at a given time so that I can print that info within `createAndInsertCandy`.

The challenge is that I need to pass in the argument to `createAndInsertCandy` as a reference to the `pthread_create` function. I'm not sure how to do that though given I'm using a loop counter to track which number thread I'm currently dispatching (it wouldn't do to pass that in by reference). I can think of a couple ugly solutions to this problem but I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution I'm missing. I'm pretty sure the solution below works except for the final argument to `pthread_create` which needs to be a reference.

```
       pthread_t factoryThreads[NUM_FACTORIES];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FACTORIES; i++) {
            pthread_t factoryThread;
            factoryThreads[i] = factoryThread;
            pthread_create(&factoryThreads[i], NULL, createAndInsertCandy, i+1);
        }
```

Comment: First of all a little note about terminology: C doesn't have *references*, the argument passed to the thread function is a generic pointer plain and simple. As for your problem, it's ugly and not all recommend it, but you *can* cast the result to a `void *`, like `(void *) (i + 1)`, and then cast the pointer back to an `int` in the thread function (`int i = (int) thePointerArgument`)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The `createAndInsertCandy` function takes awhile to execute and I need the thread number to be consistent for the duration. If I passed in `i` like that, wouldn't I need to worry about it changing on the next iteration of the for loop?

Comment: No, because you don't pass a pointer to `i`, you pass the *value* of `i + 1`. Casting a value to a pointer doesn't actually make it a pointer to the value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's good to know. Confusing though, using a pointer to pass by value runs contrary to the way I've used pointers in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution is to cast the integer to a pointer

```
pthread_create(&factoryThreads[i], NULL, createAndInsertCandy, (void *)(i+1));
```

Then you cast the pointer back to an `int` in the thread function.

The pedantic solution is to declare an array of `int` which you initialize as you create threads.

```
pthread_t factoryThreads[NUM_FACTORIES];
int args[NUM_FACTORIES];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FACTORIES; i++) {
    args[i] = i+1;
    pthread_create(&factoryThreads[i], NULL, createAndInsertCandy, &args[i]);
}
```

Note that the `args` array must remain in scope until all of the threads have retrieved their values. So, for example, if the array is declared in `main`, then `main` must not exit until the threads are done with the array. Or you could just make the array a global variable.

Comment: You might want to point out that the lifetime of the `args` array needs to be at least as long until all threads have fetched their values, which in practicality is really hard to do so one might as well make it a global variable, or allocate it dynamically and free it once all threads have been joined.

Comment: First solution gives undefined behavior and the second is implementation defined.

Comment: @2501 Thanks for that. I suggest that you expand upon your comment in a separate answer. Specifically, if you consider both of these to be unsatisfactory, then what is your suggested solution?

Comment: I was providing information about the behavior, because I think it is important it is mentioned.